# Visual Studio + SQL integration services projects

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server, integration

I am trying to install SQL Server Integration Services with Visual Studio 2019 however when I opend the exe file with SISP I am not able to select Visual Studio instance because I have the following error: "The installation of this visual studio instance is not completed you may need to restart you machine"

I am using VS on this computer for last six months installation is complet and there is no reason to display such notification.

The question is why do I recieve such notification and how to finally install SQL Server Integration services correctly on my machine?

I am using Visual Studio 16.1.4 whereas I have downloaded integration services recently thus I am trying to install version 3.0.

Comment: What build of Visual Studio 2019 are you running?  Edit your question to include this vital information.  What version of SSDT are you trying to install?  One of the things SSDT will attempt to install is a limited version of Visual Studio, so what this error message is indicating is the setup to the limited version of Visual Studio that is being installed, is not complete.  SSIS and SSDT seem to be connected.

Comment: This limited version is only installed if Visual Studio is not being detected, which is the reason knowing what version of Visual Studio and SSIS you are attempting to install and have installed is vital to answering your question.  I am indeed asking about SSDT, SSIS, and Visual Studio.  I have not made a typo.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 16.1.4 whereas I have downloaded integration services recently thus I am trying to install version 3.0.

Comment: I have the same problem and have Vs 2019 build 16.2.0

Comment: I do have the same issue. 16.9.0. I just download it from MS. The SSIS that I am trying to install it's 3.12. 
As that it's also downloaded from MS, and by the "Manage extension" feature I don't know the use of specify the versions.